# mounting a damaged USB in Cygwin

Tags: usb, data-recovery, cygwin

i read that usb devices should be auto-mounted in cygwin to their drive letter, such as /cygwin/g but that isn't happening for my damaged USB drive.  i am trying to clone it using ddrescue.  ideally i could run this from windows so that I can still have access to my computer instead of from a rescue disk, since i expect the clone of a 450gb to take *days*.

disk management recognizes the drive as physical disk #2 and assigns it a drive letter G:/

how can i mount this drive in cygwin so that i can image it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Windows has assigned drive letter G to the device, it should be automatically visible in Cygwin (i.e., a Bash shell) at `/cygdrive/g`.  If that isn't working, it is likely a result of the damage to the USB drive.

Comment: i thought that might be the case, but was hoping there was a way to mount the physical drive some other way. :/